# Why does Array.isArray not work for a typed array?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm using Chrome `Version 101.0.4951.64 (Official Build) (arm64)` on a new m1 macbook pro. Is it expected behavior that

`Array.isArray(new Float32Array([0, 1, 2]))`

returns `false`?

```js
console.log(Array.isArray(new Float32Array([1, 2, 3])));
```

Comment: Directly from [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray#description)... _"Given a [`TypedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) instance, `false` is always returned."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypedArrays aren't Arrays.

```js
console.log(new Uint32Array instanceof Array)
```

The equivalent of `Array.isArray()` for TypedArrays is [`ArrayBuffer.isView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/isView):

```js
const typed = new Float32Array(1024);
const arr = new Array(1024);

console.log(Array.isArray(typed));      // false
console.log(Array.isArray(arr));        // true
console.log(ArrayBuffer.isView(typed)); // true
console.log(ArrayBuffer.isView(arr));   // false
```

with the particularity that it will also return `true` for DataView objects.

Answer (score 0):

Typed arrays are not technically arrays, they are `TypedArray`s and have their own type:

```js
let floatArr = new Float32Array();
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(floatArr));
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call([]));
```

And according to the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays):

> JavaScript typed arrays are array-like objects
> ...
> However, typed arrays are *not* to be confused with normal arrays, as calling [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) on a typed array returns `false`.

Comment: Sure, it seems odd though that Float32Array would implement the array interface/abstractions (not sure the correct js term) but not `isArray` itself.  Especially if you consider `isArray` to be a tool to help make sure a value supports array operations etc. Based on the [ECMA docs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-isarray) for `isArray` it seems that `Float32` clearly doesn't support it and/or it [isn't an Array Exotic Object](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#array-exotic-object)?